# What are Ice Towers useful for?

Tags: bloons-td-5, bloons-td-4

The description of Ice Towers states that they "freeze bloons in its burst radius for a short time. Frozen bloons are immune to sharp objects". Considering the whole point of this game is to shoot various things (most of which are sharp!) at bloons to pop them....what good is the Ice Tower?

Comment: Get enough ice towers and you can literally go on forever on some levels.  I have one of the high scores on one of the endless levels in bloons TD 4 from ice towers + explosives, and the only reason it's not THE high score is that I got bored after leaving the iPad on for 7 days straight.

Comment: Happy to see that BTD5 hasn't been completely forgotten about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The immunity to sharp objects does not extend to explosive damage. Thus, you could combine an Ice Tower with a Bomb Tower, Mortar Tower, Monkey Apprentice, Super Monkey, or simply a Pineapple to freeze bloons in place while destroying them.

The Ice Tower also has upgrades that allow it to pop bloons as they're frozen, slow down bloons even after defrosting, and more.

Other towers also have upgrades that will allow them to pop frozen bloons, such as the Sniper Monkey, the Boomerang Thrower, and the Dartling Gun. Additionally, the Monkey Village can be upgraded to permit all towers within its range to pop any type of bloon, including frozen bloons.

In short, Ice Towers are capable of holding bloons in place for other towers to shoot at, as well as slowing down waves.

Answer (score 0):

Arctic Wind (3/2) can pop most balloons on its own, Paired with a 4/2 glaive lord around a corner makes it unstoppable, as well as a 2/3 monkey village. Also if it is 2/3, and there are normal balloons surrounding a moab, the thing basically clears the screen.